# Css style sheet in browsers, with anonymous user

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, opera

I have site, that is work perfectly in all browsers, except opera. The main page works fine, but when i open any node page(drupal 7) opera just simply doesnt download css file. Tried to clear cache, but didnt work. Any ideas what to do?

PS i just figured, that problem with logged user. If you are logged as admin, it works fine, else just dont download css

Comment: can u show me the link of your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by krumo() with unsetted persmissions for anonymous users. After i delete it from my node--xx.tpl everything become good.